# Adding new line with spaces using a variable using command sed in unix

Tags: unix, sed

I have to add new line below a specific line

but the new line contains white spaces and double quotes.

**Note new line must be added using a variable

Please help:

newline='"Cluster Synch Check Duplicate Cubes"=dword:00000001'

sed -i '/"IgnoreAllExceptions"=dword:00000000/a\'$newline'\' myfile.txt

Error:
sed: can't read Cubes"=dword:00000001: No such file or directory

Comment: search line: "IgnoreAllExceptions"=dword:00000000

Sample input "Cluster Synch Check Duplicate Cubes"=dword:00000001

Desired Output:

"IgnoreAllExceptions"=dword:00000000
"Cluster, Synch, Check, Duplicate, Cubes"=dword:00000001

Answer (score 0):

You mean:

```
sed -i '/"IgnoreAllExceptions"=dword:00000000/a'"$newline" myfile.txt
```